# How to specify HTTP response code in next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a Next.js v12 application written in TypeScript.

I have a `_error.tsx` page providing custom UI experience for various errors, including `410`, `404` and other ones. The issue is, whatever API error triggers the appearance of this page on the server-side, the client browser GETs this page from server with the HTTP status code of `500`.

How could I customize that status code, so that for example the page for `410` actually has the HTTP status code of `410`?

Comment: Make sure your server code handles all errors so it doesn't give a 500 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to find the solution on my own.

It's a little bit counter-intuitive, but to get the desired behavior you should just directly set the value of `statusCode` of the `res` object coming into `getInitialProps` of the said `_error.tsx` page.

Along these lines:

```
ErrorPage.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }: NextPageContext) => {
  const statusCode =
    (err as AxiosError)?.response?.status ?? res?.statusCode ?? err?.statusCode ?? undefined;
  if (res && statusCode) {
    res.statusCode = statusCode;
  }
  const text = String(res?.statusMessage || err?.message || err);
  return { statusCode, text };
};
```